# What next after purchasing Microsoft 365?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-2013

My boss purchased Microsoft 365 which came in three products. He now challenged me to design a management system, like an employee self-service portal. I am hereby looking for advice on where to start or which product to use, since I am new to this.

I have tried a bit of research and I came across the Sharepoint platform which can be used to create workflows and automate tasks. Is this the right way forward or there is a better and standard way to do it? Please somebody advise me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are on the right track if your goal is to create an employee portal. SharePoint and Azure Active Directory are the right services to start with. There is no best practice per say since it is all code and you could even build your own .NET app from scratch if you wanted to do that, but SharePoint is useful because it can give you some frameworks for getting something like an employee self-service portal set up quickly.

There are some good tutorials out there for this already:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NX0oh3VSNU
https://resources.techcommunity.microsoft.com/resources/build-modern-intranet-on-sharepoint-office-365/

This one even has some best practices for design choices:
https://blog.mydock365.com/employee-portal-design-sharepoint-intranet/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is very useful to me. Great ! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to explore the training portal for Microsoft 365 and SharePoint specifically:

Here is a link to the free SharePoint training resources offered there:
[Microsoft Support: SharePoint video training](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-video-training-cb8ef501-84db-4427-ac77-ec2009fb8e23?wt.mc_id=otc_home)

This site also offers some fantastic infographics and cheat-sheets for SharePoint:

[How to customize your SharePoint website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-customize-your-sharepoint-website-11de936c-8fed-4474-ac58-583d0c38ac12)

[Office cheat sheets: SharePoint Online](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/4/C3468197-CE05-4738-A1D4-707B4738723A/SPO%20QS.pdf)

Check out the SharePoint Look Book:

[SharePoint Look Book](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/)